Is the expression "cá pra mim" idiomatic?
I know the meaning of the expression "cá pra mim" but I don't know if it is an idiomatic expression or not.

I think the word "cá" is more of an intensifier that it is about "mim".

Yes, it's very idiomatic and even found in dictionaries, e.g., Aulete:

cá
8. Usualmente em combinação com a 1a pessoa (singular ou plural) para reforçar a ideia de que aquilo que é dito é opinião pessoal de quem fala, ou lhe diz respeito de modo direto, especial ou íntimo; para mim (nós); quanto a mim (nós); no que me (nos) concerne: Cá estamos a te esperar. ; Penso cá [ou: cá para mim] que cometes grande tolice.

Freely translated:

Usually in combination with the 1st person (singular or plural) to reinforce the idea that what is being said is the personal opinion of the person speaking, or concerns them in a direct, special or intimate way; for me (us); as for me (us); as far as I (we) are concerned: Here we are waiting for you. ; For me [or: from where I stand] you're making a big mistake.

